# Ionic textarea get value with post reqest

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, post, http-post

I have a ion-textarea , a service and a typescript and I am trying to send a post request to get what the user typed in the textarea after the user pressed submit button . How can I achieve this, really appreciate your help.

```
<ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-textarea
          placeholder="Enter feedback"
          [(ngModel)]="textArea"
          ></ion-textarea>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
<ion-button (click)="submitF()">Submit</ion-button>
```

service.ts

```
 feedback(textArea: string) {
    return this.http.post<{ message: string }>(
      this.url + "/p/feedback",
      {
        textArea,
      }
    );
  }
```

What exactly shold I do after this , a subscription in typescript? Can someone please help me?
Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`feedback()` returns a `oberservable` which you can `subscribe` to. For example:

```
          this.service.feedback(this.textArea)
             .subscribe(
                (result: {message: string}) => console.log(result.message),
                error => console.error(error) // log any errors
          );
```

Comment: Hi @Mike S. and thaks for responding. I've done that and I get a 422 error when i press submit , that console log there should show me the user message in console or ? I uploaded a image. so you can see the current error . https://imgur.com/mwkgVNJ Its saying in the error tab that its invalid message , do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: @tirbushonn23 That error came from your backend, it has nothing to do with your service call (which is perfectly fine). I'll extend the answer to also catch any errors that occur though.